# Is there ever a reason to use std::list?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

After having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402483/why-is-it-so-slow-iterating-over-a-big-stdlist) and looking at some [results here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/), it seems like one should altogether completely avoid lists in C++. I always expected that linked lists would be the containers of choice for cases where I only need to iterate over all the contents because insertion is a matter of pointer manipulation and there is never a need to reallocate.

Apparently, because of "cache locality," lists are iterated over very slowly, so any benefit from having to use less reserve memory or faster addition (which is not that much faster, it seems, from the second link) doesn't seem worth it.

**Having said that, when should I, from a performance standpoint, use `std::list` over `std::deque` or, if possible, `std::vector`?**

On a side note, will `std::forward_list` also have lots of cache misses?

Comment: You can use a list even with uncopyable, unmovable types (and still be able to insert in the middle).

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471432/in-which-scenario-do-i-use-a-particular-stl-container

Comment: @Borgleader: That is just a theoretical question, which need not be appropriate for practical implementations. That is, on paper insertion in the middle of a list is `O(1)` and insertion in the middle of a vector is `O(n)`, so the first should be preferred... except that the hidden constant in `O(1)` might be larger than `O(n)`. Quoting Stepanov `O(log N)` for a couple hundred million elements is a small number, so you can call it constant time with a somehow large factor. The same applies here... `N*very_small` might be smaller than `1*very_large`

Comment: I'm using `std::list` in a situation where the allocated objects need to be pinned to their memory location with a custom allocator that adds metadata to each link. It's probably the only time I don't think I could have used something else instead.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues given your presence [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist), do you mind answering if you think this applies to Java? At that high of a level, does `LinkedList<>` introduce additional iteration cost?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Some of the answers, in particular the accepted one about concurrent data structures, is quite practical. It's just not really applicable to the specific linked list variant that is `std::list`, because some of its assumptions (including being C++, if you want to call that an assumption) and abstractions clash with the requirements for concurrent modifications.

Comment: VF1, In Java you have to opt between the bad and the worse, since none of those containers provide locality of data (Java using references for everything). If you care about locality of data, choose a different language.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez I did, hehe...

Comment: @delnan: Well, concurrency is out of the question with `std::list`, so it does not weight in the decision of `std::list` vs. `std::vector`, so again it is a theoretical question vs. a practical concrete one.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You may have a different definition of theoretical. I'd say it is just not applicable here. I would not say it is a theoretical question, perhaps more *general* because it's about all kinds of linked lists in any kind of language, not about `std::list` in C++ specifically. As a consequence, some answers to *that* question don't apply to this question because they don't meet the criteria, but that doesn't make them theoretical, it just makes them not relevant. Other answers are pretty much like the answers we're seeing here, only less C++ specific in their terminology.

Comment: To add my two cents, I would also point out that one of the viable alternatives is also a vector of pointers (e.g., `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` or `boost::stable_vector`). This solves most of the expensive-to-copy issues while retaining random-access, and getting persistent positions (in actual memory). But you get locality of reference issues comparable to linked-lists, but less memory overhead. Also, most things that are expensive to copy and are cheap to move (C++11). I don't find `std::list` very useful at all in actual implementations, can't recall the last time I chose to use it.

Comment: @delnan: The tags in the other question are [language-agnostic] [data-structure] [linked-list]. That makes it theoretical.  The first answer is (in a generic way) that there can be an impact on concurrent implementations, relevant in a theoretical way, not in a practical way for `std::list` (*If `std::list` were concurrent, that would be an advantage* it isn't). But I think we are just arguing the terms, if you prefer not applicable here, I am fine by that.

Comment: From a performance standpoint, the best reason to use std::list is so that when later on your app is suffering badly for performance and needs "an optimziation pass", you can replace it with another data structure and look like a hero.

Comment: [Number crunching: Why you should never, ever, EVER use linked-list in your code again](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/)

Comment: i imagine that if you are doing active rendering where race to sleep is impossible, and doing a calculation which is done either once or on user demand, then using linked lists greatly simplify your code. that said they are one of the worst thing you can do inside loops unless they are stack linked lists that are linked with scopes in depth. When designing algorithms that insert values between elements, especially many at once, for maintainability, such as tessellation of triangles, lists get proofs of concepts done significantly faster.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> When should I, from a performance standpoint, use `std::list`

From a performance standpoint, rarely. The only situation that comes to mind is if you have many lists that you need to split and join to form other lists; a linked list can do this without allocating memory or moving objects.

The real benefit of `list` is stability: elements don't need to be movable, and iterators and references are never invalidated unless they refer to an element that's been erased.

> On a side note, will `std::forward_list` also have lots of cache misses?

Yes; it's still a linked list.

Comment: Like Yakk mentioned in his answer, if my design requires a container that keeps its objects in place, I should just be using pointers anyway (from both a practical implementation and design perspective).

Comment: @VF1: Yes, there are other ways to get a container of stable objects (or pointers thereto). `list` has the slight advantage of managing the  objects' lifetime, so you don't need to mess around with smart pointers or extra containers for the objects.

Answer (score 23):

`std::list` is useful in a few corner cases.

However, the general rule of C++ sequential containers is "if your algorithm are compatible, use `std::vector`.  If your algorithms are not compatible, modify your algorithms so you can use `std::vector`."

Exceptions exist, and here is an attempt to exhaustively list reasons that `std::list` is a better choice:

1. When you need to (A) insert into the middle of the container and (B) you need each objects location in memory to be stable.  Requirement (B) can usually be removed by having a non-stable container consisting of pointers to elements, so this isn't a strong reason to use `std::list`.
2. When you need to (A) insert or delete in the middle of the container (B) orders of magnitude more often than you need to iterate over the container.  This is also an extreme corner case: in order to find the element to delete from a `list`, you usually need to iterate!

Which leads to

3. you need (A) insert or delete in the middle of the container and (B) have iterators to all other elements remain valid.  This ends up being a hidden requirement of case 1 and case 2: it is hard to delete or insert more often than you iterate when you don't have persistant iterators, and the stability of iterators and of objects is highly related.
4. the final case, is the case of splicing was once a reason to use `std::list`.

Back in C++03, all versions of `std::list::splice` could (in theory) be done in O(1) time.  However, the extremely efficient forms of `splice` required that `size` be an O(n) operation.  C++11 has required that `size` on a `list` be O(1), so `splice`'s extreme efficiency is limited to the "splicing an entire other list" and "self-splicing a sublist" case.  In the case of single element splice, this is just an insert and delete.  In the case of sub range splice, the code now has to visit *every* node in the splice just to count them in order to maintain `size` as O(1) (except in self-splicing).

So, if you are doing only whole-`list` splices, or self-list subrange `splice`s, `list` can do these operations much faster than other non-list containers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning stable containers. And case 2-3 is quite a corner case indeed because for the most part this case describes a situation where you need individual dynamically allocated objects (i.e., "persistent iterators" become "(smart-)pointers"), with the only difference being the need for *occasional* traversals. These *occasional* traversals are rarely worth the overhead (previous / next pointers) as opposed to context-specific alternatives (e.g., traversing the objects that contain the persistent "pointers").

Answer (score 9):

The biggest improvement that `std::list` can provide is when you're moving one or more elements from the middle of one list into another list. This `splice` operation is extremely efficient on `list` while it may involve allocation and movement of items in random access containers such as `vector`. That said, this comes of very rarely and much of the time `vector` is your best container in terms of performance an simplicity.

Always profile your code if you suspect performance problems with a container choice.

Comment: Forgot about `splice`! Yes, I suppose for certain purposes, where an operation like that is needed, it would be better to use `list`.

Comment: Splice is much slower than it could be in C++03, because `list` requires an O(1) `size` in C++11.  Now, I'm not sure if anyone actually wrote an O(n) `size` list, but ...

Comment: @Yakk: yes, such a shame too. `splice` was one of the best reason to use lists and it got crippled in C++11 *just* so that `size` could be O(1)... I would have much preferred removing `size` altogether or changing its name to avoid inadvertent use.

Comment: @MatthiewM. While it would have made the standard more verbose, a kind of `size` being dirty would solve the problem.  That way, `splice` could be O(1), and `size` could be O(1), but `splice` *then* `size` would be O(n).  The downside is that this O(n) cost would be born by both lists, and not limited to the amount of spliced data.  I cannot think of a practical way to have a `size` with efficient lazy splice-accounting in it...

Answer (score 7):

You chose `std::list` over `std::deque` and `std::vector` (and other contiguous memory  containers) when you frequently add/remove items in the middle of your container, [see also](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4887/when-should-vector-list-be-used).

Comment: Although in that case, you should first consider whether you *need* to insert in the middle, or to preserve the order when you erase from the middle; and if you do, whether the container will be large enough that a list is actually faster.

Comment: Also, this is only true if you already have an iterator for the position where you want to add/remove, or have a cheap way to get one.