# Why is my A* implementation ~20% slower than its JS counterpart?

Tags: c++, performance

***Note:** The code is built with `std=c++17 -O3 -ffast-math`, and the result are the same regardless of whether it's built by GCC 13 or Clang. It's unlikely to be just a matter of enabling the compiler optimizations.*

I was interested to compare the performances of Wasm vs both JS and C++, so I started to write a benchmark. Since I tend to prefer "real life situations" rather than just benchmarking loops, I implemented A* while using the same code structure to be sure I was testing apples and apples (the functions are named the same, the semantics are the same, etc).

I was surprised to find out that my JS implementation is faster than the C++ one by a non-insignificant factor when run through Node.js (on a M1, but I got the same results on an older mac):

```
$ ./native
Avg 113.52

$ node ./MyAstar.js
Avg 89.48
```

I imagine V8 somehow manages to optimize the code better than the C++ compiler, but I find that a little difficult to believe, so I'd like to understand what's happening exactly. Did I make an obvious performance mistake when implementing the C++ code?

The C++ code (note that I compressed the maps using a dictionary so it'd fit inside the SO max post size):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(void) : x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){}

    Point operator+(Point const & other) const {
        return Point(this->x + other.x, this->y + other.y);
    }

    bool operator==(Point const & other) const {
        return this->x == other.x && this->y == other.y;
    }

    bool operator!=(Point const & other) const {
        return this->x != other.x || this->y != other.y;
    }
};

static Point const allNeighbours[] = {
//  { -1, -1 },
//  {  1, -1 },
//  { -1,  1 },
//  {  1,  1 },
    {  0, -1 },
    { -1,  0 },
    {  0,  1 },
    {  1,  0 },
};

struct Node {
    Point position;
    Point parent;

    int cost;
    int distance;

    Node(Point const& position, Point const& parent, int cost, int distance)
        : position(position)
        , parent(parent)
        , cost(cost)
        , distance(distance)
        {}

    bool operator==(Point const& point) const {
        return this->position == point;
    }
};

class AStar {
public:
    static std::optional<std::list<Point>> search(char const * map, int width, int height, Point const& start, Point const& end) {
        AStar engine(map, width, height, start, end);

        if (engine.search()) {
            return engine.path();
        } else {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }

private:
    AStar(char const * map, int width, int height, Point const& start, Point const& end)
        : m_map(map)
        , m_width(width)
        , m_height(height)
        , m_start(start)
        , m_end(end)
        {}

public:
    int getDistanceToEnd(Point const& point) const {
        int x = m_end.x - point.x;
        int y = m_end.y - point.y;
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    bool isValid(Point const& point) const {
        return point.x >= 0 && point.x < m_width && point.y >= 0 && point.y < m_height;
    }

    int getCost(Point const& point) const {
        return m_map[point.y * m_width + point.x];
    }

    bool isPointRegistered(Point const& p, int distCost) {
        std::list<Node>::iterator it;

        it = std::find(m_closed.begin(), m_closed.end(), p);
        if (it != m_closed.end()) {
            if (it->cost + it->distance < distCost) {
                return true;
            } else {
                m_closed.erase(it);
                return false;
            }
        }

        it = std::find(m_open.begin(), m_open.end(), p);
        if (it != m_open.end()) {
            if (it->cost + it->distance < distCost) {
                return true;
            } else {
                m_open.erase(it);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool search(void) {
        m_open.emplace_back(m_start, Point(), 0, this->getDistanceToEnd(m_start));

        while (!m_open.empty()) {
            Node node = m_open.front();
            m_open.pop_front();

            m_closed.emplace_back(node);

            if (this->fillOpen(node)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    std::list<Point> path(void) {
        std::list<Point> path = {m_end};

        auto & backNode = m_closed.back();
        path.emplace_front(backNode.position);
        Point parent = backNode.parent;

        for (auto it = m_closed.rbegin(); it != m_closed.rend(); ++it) {
            auto position = it->position;

            if (position == parent && position != m_start) {
                path.push_front(position);
                parent = it->parent;
            }
        }

        path.emplace_front(m_start);

        return path;
    }

    bool fillOpen(Node const & node) {
        for (int t = 0; t < sizeof(allNeighbours) / sizeof(allNeighbours[0]); ++t) {
            Point neighbour = node.position + allNeighbours[t];
            if (neighbour == m_end)
                return true;

            char cost = this->getCost(neighbour);
            if (this->isValid(neighbour) && cost != 0) {
                int neighbourCost = node.cost + cost;
                int neighbourDistance = this->getDistanceToEnd(neighbour);

                if (!this->isPointRegistered(neighbour, neighbourCost + neighbourDistance)) {
                    m_open.emplace_back(neighbour, node.position, neighbourCost, neighbourDistance);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    char const * m_map;

    int m_width;
    int m_height;

    Point m_start;
    Point m_end;

    std::list<Node> m_open;
    std::list<Node> m_closed;
};

std::string decompress(const std::string& compressed, const std::unordered_map<char, std::string>& dictionary) {
    std::string decompressed;
    for (auto it = compressed.begin(); it != compressed.end(); ++it) {
        auto match = dictionary.find(*it);
        if (match != dictionary.end()) {
            for (auto c : match->second) {
                decompressed += c - '0';
            }
        } else {
            decompressed += *it - '0';
        }
    }
    return decompressed;
}

std::string g_map = decompress("ccccccccccccccc0011101110{eFqQxxeQxQnxO1001010001uHvHmimjHimI$T[kbbQDOt+ra^UFb1110010000yKwuIlNMyHvzl$0100001011ef^arnQnb)rnxF]lvWjopmyRvHmcz|nhbdhnbUAUar(n;scwwlBTPW@WsRmzrFVaFqtefF*XaYfJ$imlwilTSsyIKM}kbd&LLgebX#Ddh1001000101MssSpvj$yGwEHi0100101011gdnqXXrtUfaOrU:pCKCmoyivlJEyy0000001111gOefV(b^Yx)&gV1111100000WEEI@lPPomySyE0000010011hFLf_h)fQeUVkA1111101001cGM$jTGsBlv%PKpqdfhbAaQknrbghhiiMRPT$Czsi%Gp%0010111011LnbfknbLn^DgXf1001000100NHj$JPH@BvjGHM,(fhbgUh_eng_ee1110000100lPcImKBIzBIvzC.beFrqfa_^krrhh1111100100JSPBSpHGzImHEZ|f#OtOnatnDVfed/MKcT$pvupizjCiGbaFgQggqnd)deLDJjNZRIiSpjviRpM0010101010rq+&+VqdnAe(tA1001010101iwITjiRJBwRswi0000111010k#ft*^tkk#arkV1010000001yNpmjPHCKSMMCi0101001110*(dqYknAOqfff^]jlJSuKNpc%IMjW|+gkAk(eQ(aDdXa/IIizWRJTuTCCscWrnUndxfak^n#r#UmNjoCBljIzoCj@@0011111110nrhDag*rf(ehhf1000000000pZNylyvuj%zcC%0100111111xrQOxd+ebbb(Lt1110010001RsHTooImw%H%Pl.tXfeQhdYk*XnVx]KKjlBslmysooKR0101010010xeXDaQadtqxYbF/cPuJGRlJSNBHwGN&k#AkaxU&xa*#+QEGyRMsRJuBpjSIs<nbqraqAbgxY&kY>lBCyzMSZvcuBPE0100111111aDF^ag^b)OVqdx1110000000MIBzCyjljpJSmo0001001111nggbfYXarXa&DQ1011100100oBpiWuoMyZCzIo0100000011qUhUkFA#Dbe_*h?uIiW%NKEKTKW$pBqUeabdqxtedahdeuTCE%sisSRyT$Mz<geFgnbd&(V_Ybg1000000100sKCWpoMSoEIyJI0100111110nfL_qQabQh*kU)1010010000vlIvwmCsmojB@l~LF*gkaV*#b*t^{1110100101EppPipCv@vHBGl0101010011VXndVtxg_Xe&rh1110101001CmGoiSHKIoSSGTBFqaYqOfOra&AnaVNEcJulvKpvRvN$@0011111010axUAqadnghnVnA1001000101PHiTCzoGPjNJsl,kaAAhaqUaUxXQq:KvNpoCwzB@ooow0101001010F)OaqO#ObgqqQV1110100001PlzzPEEEGZwEMi0100000011DxFAkAAOUaUFnk?Huczwyvu@zviHHNfAqhefgqkenefeVWlyuuTPuBwmRlEJ0010101010hdeb)ftYaD(FLb1000010101%%RZsvimmIlGv%0100111010Aaq+Q_AkkDakDt1010010001w$iIoWPKzCCTiu.A*krtkk#)habtq1111100001BjmHHzPwjoH$iK0000010011ALDehXLkdQF&^Y1111101001ppjENo%MuoNcvoGrdnOxOVA&Ye{DhrJ@BlNECKcJzSJWZ<_ObaAdhFb)#kUg>jTMjPjNTujzizG[X&bXV*fAY)beLr:oEimEJW@ZjCuzZ~YfaVF)kgddAgLb1110100100iyMz$sKm$iKsz%0001000010LU)_xtrbtaxqgh1010111000Gvjj$SjGwNNwPRPafXDAkXbLtxfd{bGCuJ@joTGBNsiSB}e&D_gqt#tarUba1001010000ucMZKEmwBGyHIv[VeFDhFXbhaDdf)1010010000IMSJNmsmK@IHRK0101001010*dkd{YbYf)rdef1110100101ZCIRco@mKZujMG0001010011Dq*tx(AQDn#ddk1110101000IwZmocSoypKKi@v_^Yth&&YdYbfdLbWvSBNTwKoiPWm%C}g#dxgbd(dd*fDf1001000100w@yB%ZywomyGJM0100111010LDdahrfO(dD#Lf1010010001ZCmN$%pcEZZwl$0101001011rLtQh^t&Ogg^xh1011100001svBoG@KuEGvvRp0101000011trV{bfXVkrrXOD;EH@clJmJysym@JBAeLhx^^)eXDgULrBzlsSwWplGypCGs0011111110hhdqOLtAgf{eDQ>ujJuwlE@GpcHyu0100111010eb^q#hFLknxdd#1010000101GwT$w$BNivCHoP0001001010gLgxVhahebFDef1110100101%pscHiopuzBHGp0101010010htd(d^tYOgdQDa1110101001$yMRPWKClCsMTJpn+aQf*dFxqXftdhmjlmpZyBRisCmRl0010111010bFO*aeeOVdLYan1001010101wTEjwclWNMvNyj0000111011kbLgkehaqFgxD+1110010000H%WPHMuSwuszmI0101001110fb+LQdkAU#r_qr1010100000J%JGRCIpI@MJSZ0100010011fgbD(akgVeLb&r?sZRPumwWEE@$uZNdYhaOA#gLtaXarezusNlplBvucsosz}aYt)FgdQ#&xQeU1000000100Z$TjlMsm@RBoEJ,Dnt*gFkDAq#eeL1010010100isRjZczpwiwliT~UaA+b{bYO^#xeO1111100101jzvjGEiJSWEcuc0100010010bb)*dLfgAk^tg&;wiWj%PsmpEWyZEl&OaFte((x{eFtF(ccccccccccccccc0", {{'a',"1110111011"},{'b',"1011101110"},{'c',"0000000000"},{'d',"1110111010"},{'e',"1110111110"},{'f',"1110101110"},{'g',"1011101011"},{'h',"1111101110"},{'i',"0101000001"},{'j',"0001010101"},{'k',"1010111011"},{'l',"0000010000"},{'m',"0100000101"},{'n',"1111101011"},{'o',"0000000101"},{'p',"0000010100"},{'q',"1011111110"},{'r',"1011101010"},{'s',"0000010101"},{'t',"1011111011"},{'u',"0100000001"},{'v',"0001010100"},{'w',"0101000000"},{'x',"1111111011"},{'y',"0101000101"},{'z',"0001010000"},{'A',"1011101111"},{'B',"0100000100"},{'C',"0001000001"},{'D',"1010111010"},{'E',"0001000000"},{'F',"1111101111"},{'G',"0100010100"},{'H',"0001000101"},{'I',"0101010101"},{'J',"0101010001"},{'K',"0001000100"},{'L',"1110101111"},{'M',"0001010001"},{'N',"0000000100"},{'O',"1110111111"},{'P',"0101000100"},{'Q',"1111111010"},{'R',"0000000001"},{'S',"0100000000"},{'T',"0100010000"},{'U',"1010101110"},{'V',"1010111110"},{'W',"0101010100"},{'X',"1111101010"},{'Y',"1011111010"},{'Z',"0100010101"},{'@',"0101010000"},{'#',"1010111111"},{'$',"0000010001"},{'%',"0100010001"},{'^',"1010101111"},{'&',"1011111111"},{'*',"1110101010"},{'(',"1111111110"},{')',"1110101011"},{'_',"1010101011"},{'+',"1010101010"},{'{',"1111111111"},{'}',"0011101011"},{'[',"0100101111"},{']',"1011100101"},{'|',"0000010010"},{';',"1110111001"},{':',"1110010100"},{',',"0100111011"},{'.',"0000001110"},{'/',"1011101001"},{'<',"0011101111"},{'>',"1001000000"},{'?',"1011111001"},{'~',"0001001011"}});
int const g_mapWidth = 151;
int const g_mapHeight = 151;
int const g_cycles = 100;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Point start = {1, 1};
    Point end = {g_mapWidth - 2, g_mapHeight - 2};

    auto before = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    std::optional<std::list<Point>> lastPath;
    for (int t = 0; t < g_cycles; ++t)
        lastPath = AStar::search(g_map.data(), g_mapWidth, g_mapHeight, start, end);

    auto after = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    auto totalTime = (after - before).count();

    std::cout << "Avg " << (static_cast<float>(totalTime) / g_cycles) << " " << (lastPath ? lastPath->size() : 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The JS code:

```
const allNeighbours = [
//  {x: -1, y: -1},
//  {x:  1, y: -1},
//  {x: -1, y:  1},
//  {x:  1, y:  1},
    {x:  0, y: -1},
    {x: -1, y:  0},
    {x:  0, y:  1},
    {x:  1, y:  0},
];

// Used to avoid allocations
const temporaryNeighbour = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
};

class AStar {
    static search(map, width, height, start, end) {
        const engine = new AStar(map, width, height, start, end);
    
        if (engine.search()) {
            return engine.path();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    constructor(map, width, height, start, end) {
        this.map = map;

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        this.open = [];
        this.closed = [];
    }

    getDistanceToEnd(point) {
        const x = this.end.x - point.x;
        const y = this.end.y - point.y;
        return x * x + y * y;
    }

    isValid(point) {
        return point.x >= 0 && point.x < this.width && point.y >= 0 && point.y < this.height;
    }

    getCost(point) {
        return this.map[point.y * this.width + point.x];
    }

    isPointRegistered(point, distCost) {
        const findByPosition = node => {
            return node.position.x === point.x && node.position.y === point.y;
        };

        const closedIt = this.closed.findIndex(findByPosition);
        if (closedIt !== -1) {
            const closed = this.closed[closedIt];
            if (closed.cost + closed.distance < distCost) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.closed.splice(closedIt, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }

        const openIt = this.open.findIndex(findByPosition);
        if (openIt !== -1) {
            const open = this.open[openIt];
            if (open.cost + open.distance < distCost) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.open.splice(openIt, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    search() {
        this.open.push({
            position: this.start,
            parent: {x: 0, y: 0},
            cost: 0,
            distance: this.getDistanceToEnd(this.start),
        });

        while (this.open.length > 0) {
            const node = this.open.shift();
            this.closed.push(node);

            if (this.fillOpen(node)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    path() {
        const path = [this.end];

        const backNode = this.closed[this.closed.length - 1];
        path.unshift(backNode.position);
        let parent = backNode.parent;

        for (let t = this.closed.length - 1; t >= 0; --t) {
            const node = this.closed[t];
            const {position} = node;

            if ((position.x === parent.x && position.y === parent.y) && (position.x !== this.start.x || position.y !== this.start.y)) {
                path.unshift(position);
                parent = node.parent;
            }
        }

        path.unshift(this.start);

        return path;
    }

    fillOpen(node) {
        for (let t = 0; t < allNeighbours.length; ++t) {
            temporaryNeighbour.x = node.position.x + allNeighbours[t].x;
            temporaryNeighbour.y = node.position.y + allNeighbours[t].y;
            if (temporaryNeighbour.x === this.end.x && temporaryNeighbour.y === this.end.y)
                return true;

            const cost = this.getCost(temporaryNeighbour);
            if (this.isValid(temporaryNeighbour) && cost !== 0) {
                const neighbourCost = node.cost + cost;
                const neighbourDistance = this.getDistanceToEnd(temporaryNeighbour);

                if (!this.isPointRegistered(temporaryNeighbour, neighbourCost + neighbourDistance)) {
                    this.open.push({
                        position: {x: temporaryNeighbour.x, y: temporaryNeighbour.y},
                        parent: node.position,
                        cost: neighbourCost,
                        distance: neighbourDistance,
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

if (require.main === module) {
    function decompress(compressed, dictionaryEntries) {
        const dictionary = new Map(dictionaryEntries);
        return new Uint8Array([...compressed].flatMap(sym => {
            return [...dictionary.get(sym) ?? [sym]].map(sym => sym === `1` ? 1 : 0);
        }));
    }

    const map = decompress(`ccccccccccccccc0011101110{eFqQxxeQxQnxO1001010001uHvHmimjHimI$T[kbbQDOt+ra^UFb1110010000yKwuIlNMyHvzl$0100001011ef^arnQnb)rnxF]lvWjopmyRvHmcz|nhbdhnbUAUar(n;scwwlBTPW@WsRmzrFVaFqtefF*XaYfJ$imlwilTSsyIKM}kbd&LLgebX#Ddh1001000101MssSpvj$yGwEHi0100101011gdnqXXrtUfaOrU:pCKCmoyivlJEyy0000001111gOefV(b^Yx)&gV1111100000WEEI@lPPomySyE0000010011hFLf_h)fQeUVkA1111101001cGM$jTGsBlv%PKpqdfhbAaQknrbghhiiMRPT$Czsi%Gp%0010111011LnbfknbLn^DgXf1001000100NHj$JPH@BvjGHM,(fhbgUh_eng_ee1110000100lPcImKBIzBIvzC.beFrqfa_^krrhh1111100100JSPBSpHGzImHEZ|f#OtOnatnDVfed/MKcT$pvupizjCiGbaFgQggqnd)deLDJjNZRIiSpjviRpM0010101010rq+&+VqdnAe(tA1001010101iwITjiRJBwRswi0000111010k#ft*^tkk#arkV1010000001yNpmjPHCKSMMCi0101001110*(dqYknAOqfff^]jlJSuKNpc%IMjW|+gkAk(eQ(aDdXa/IIizWRJTuTCCscWrnUndxfak^n#r#UmNjoCBljIzoCj@@0011111110nrhDag*rf(ehhf1000000000pZNylyvuj%zcC%0100111111xrQOxd+ebbb(Lt1110010001RsHTooImw%H%Pl.tXfeQhdYk*XnVx]KKjlBslmysooKR0101010010xeXDaQadtqxYbF/cPuJGRlJSNBHwGN&k#AkaxU&xa*#+QEGyRMsRJuBpjSIs<nbqraqAbgxY&kY>lBCyzMSZvcuBPE0100111111aDF^ag^b)OVqdx1110000000MIBzCyjljpJSmo0001001111nggbfYXarXa&DQ1011100100oBpiWuoMyZCzIo0100000011qUhUkFA#Dbe_*h?uIiW%NKEKTKW$pBqUeabdqxtedahdeuTCE%sisSRyT$Mz<geFgnbd&(V_Ybg1000000100sKCWpoMSoEIyJI0100111110nfL_qQabQh*kU)1010010000vlIvwmCsmojB@l~LF*gkaV*#b*t^{1110100101EppPipCv@vHBGl0101010011VXndVtxg_Xe&rh1110101001CmGoiSHKIoSSGTBFqaYqOfOra&AnaVNEcJulvKpvRvN$@0011111010axUAqadnghnVnA1001000101PHiTCzoGPjNJsl,kaAAhaqUaUxXQq:KvNpoCwzB@ooow0101001010F)OaqO#ObgqqQV1110100001PlzzPEEEGZwEMi0100000011DxFAkAAOUaUFnk?Huczwyvu@zviHHNfAqhefgqkenefeVWlyuuTPuBwmRlEJ0010101010hdeb)ftYaD(FLb1000010101%%RZsvimmIlGv%0100111010Aaq+Q_AkkDakDt1010010001w$iIoWPKzCCTiu.A*krtkk#)habtq1111100001BjmHHzPwjoH$iK0000010011ALDehXLkdQF&^Y1111101001ppjENo%MuoNcvoGrdnOxOVA&Ye{DhrJ@BlNECKcJzSJWZ<_ObaAdhFb)#kUg>jTMjPjNTujzizG[X&bXV*fAY)beLr:oEimEJW@ZjCuzZ~YfaVF)kgddAgLb1110100100iyMz$sKm$iKsz%0001000010LU)_xtrbtaxqgh1010111000Gvjj$SjGwNNwPRPafXDAkXbLtxfd{bGCuJ@joTGBNsiSB}e&D_gqt#tarUba1001010000ucMZKEmwBGyHIv[VeFDhFXbhaDdf)1010010000IMSJNmsmK@IHRK0101001010*dkd{YbYf)rdef1110100101ZCIRco@mKZujMG0001010011Dq*tx(AQDn#ddk1110101000IwZmocSoypKKi@v_^Yth&&YdYbfdLbWvSBNTwKoiPWm%C}g#dxgbd(dd*fDf1001000100w@yB%ZywomyGJM0100111010LDdahrfO(dD#Lf1010010001ZCmN$%pcEZZwl$0101001011rLtQh^t&Ogg^xh1011100001svBoG@KuEGvvRp0101000011trV{bfXVkrrXOD;EH@clJmJysym@JBAeLhx^^)eXDgULrBzlsSwWplGypCGs0011111110hhdqOLtAgf{eDQ>ujJuwlE@GpcHyu0100111010eb^q#hFLknxdd#1010000101GwT$w$BNivCHoP0001001010gLgxVhahebFDef1110100101%pscHiopuzBHGp0101010010htd(d^tYOgdQDa1110101001$yMRPWKClCsMTJpn+aQf*dFxqXftdhmjlmpZyBRisCmRl0010111010bFO*aeeOVdLYan1001010101wTEjwclWNMvNyj0000111011kbLgkehaqFgxD+1110010000H%WPHMuSwuszmI0101001110fb+LQdkAU#r_qr1010100000J%JGRCIpI@MJSZ0100010011fgbD(akgVeLb&r?sZRPumwWEE@$uZNdYhaOA#gLtaXarezusNlplBvucsosz}aYt)FgdQ#&xQeU1000000100Z$TjlMsm@RBoEJ,Dnt*gFkDAq#eeL1010010100isRjZczpwiwliT~UaA+b{bYO^#xeO1111100101jzvjGEiJSWEcuc0100010010bb)*dLfgAk^tg&;wiWj%PsmpEWyZEl&OaFte((x{eFtF(ccccccccccccccc0`, [[`a`,`1110111011`],[`b`,`1011101110`],[`c`,`0000000000`],[`d`,`1110111010`],[`e`,`1110111110`],[`f`,`1110101110`],[`g`,`1011101011`],[`h`,`1111101110`],[`i`,`0101000001`],[`j`,`0001010101`],[`k`,`1010111011`],[`l`,`0000010000`],[`m`,`0100000101`],[`n`,`1111101011`],[`o`,`0000000101`],[`p`,`0000010100`],[`q`,`1011111110`],[`r`,`1011101010`],[`s`,`0000010101`],[`t`,`1011111011`],[`u`,`0100000001`],[`v`,`0001010100`],[`w`,`0101000000`],[`x`,`1111111011`],[`y`,`0101000101`],[`z`,`0001010000`],[`A`,`1011101111`],[`B`,`0100000100`],[`C`,`0001000001`],[`D`,`1010111010`],[`E`,`0001000000`],[`F`,`1111101111`],[`G`,`0100010100`],[`H`,`0001000101`],[`I`,`0101010101`],[`J`,`0101010001`],[`K`,`0001000100`],[`L`,`1110101111`],[`M`,`0001010001`],[`N`,`0000000100`],[`O`,`1110111111`],[`P`,`0101000100`],[`Q`,`1111111010`],[`R`,`0000000001`],[`S`,`0100000000`],[`T`,`0100010000`],[`U`,`1010101110`],[`V`,`1010111110`],[`W`,`0101010100`],[`X`,`1111101010`],[`Y`,`1011111010`],[`Z`,`0100010101`],[`@`,`0101010000`],[`#`,`1010111111`],[`$`,`0000010001`],[`%`,`0100010001`],[`^`,`1010101111`],[`&`,`1011111111`],[`*`,`1110101010`],[`(`,`1111111110`],[`)`,`1110101011`],[`_`,`1010101011`],[`+`,`1010101010`],[`{`,`1111111111`],[`}`,`0011101011`],[`[`,`0100101111`],[`]`,`1011100101`],[`|`,`0000010010`],[`;`,`1110111001`],[`:`,`1110010100`],[`,`,`0100111011`],[`.`,`0000001110`],[`/`,`1011101001`],[`<`,`0011101111`],[`>`,`1001000000`],[`?`,`1011111001`],[`~`,`0001001011`]]);
    const mapWidth = 151;
    const mapHeight = 151;
    const cycles = 100;

    const start = {x: 1, y: 1};
    const end = {x: mapWidth - 2, y: mapHeight - 2};

    const now = Date.now();

    let lastPath;
    for (let t = 0; t < cycles; ++t)
        lastPath = AStar.search(map, mapWidth, mapHeight, start, end);

    const totalTime = Date.now() - now;

    console.log(`Avg`, totalTime / cycles, lastPath?.length);
}
```

Comment: `static std::optional<std::list<Point>> search` - that is a potentially very expensive copy you are returning

Comment: Your post title suggests that the JS version is slower. You should fix this.

Comment: `std::list` is notoriously slow in most usecases, replace with `std::vector`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I believe the A* algorithm requires both removing elements from the middle of the data structure, and adding them at the front / back. I'm not sure a vector would allow that without expensive copies.

Comment: Then `std::deque`.

Comment: Usually it can be very insightul when you run your code through a profiler. It will show you where your code spents the most time on. And it might point you to the place where you do too much work.

Comment: @MaëlNison Tha A* should not modify a datastructure at all. You just need some administration of where you've been and this should be seperate from the graph

Comment: Chances are, std::vector is still faster than std::list. std::deque is a bad structure for in-the-middle operations, btw.

Comment: @MaëlNison Try posting the C++ and JS versions separately at CodeReview.SE to get better versions. Then compare those.

Comment: `path()` requires making a duplicate, and a completely useless copy of an entire `std::list`, which will do nothing except waste time. Not 100% sure, but having `path()` return a `std::move`d list will probably optimize away the duplicate list. Also, `search()` leaks memory, and does an absolutely useless dynamic scope instantiation (which is leaked). This is a typical result of writing either Java, Javascript, or C#, using C++'s syntax.

Comment: You're going to have to do *some* pruning down of these two large programs for your code to be on-topic here. See [mcve].

Comment: your javascript code isn't using a linked list, its using an array which is roughly equivalent to a `std::vector`, this does indicate that a linear list is faster than a linked list with modern CPUs

Comment: [Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo)

Comment: Indeed, switching from `std::list` to `std::vector` (and replacing the `pop_front` call) brought the iteration speed to 18.56ms vs the previous 110ms. I wouldn't have imagined that erasing from arbitrary places in a vector could be that insignificant in terms of perfs compared to using a linked list. Thanks for the documentation, @Evg.

Comment: [Is there ever a reason to use std::list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18449038/995714), [Bjarne Stroustrup says we must avoid linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34170566/995714), [Why you should never, ever, EVER use linked-list in your code again](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/), [Are lists evil? -- Bjarne Stroustrup](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists), [Don’t use std::list](http://danglingpointers.com/post/dont-use-std-list/)

Comment: see https://quick-bench.com/q/Mwvs4dgCtHq0ZyhzpstMgsCTmPo. Unless you are using large objects the indirection cost, iteration cost and non-locality of linked lists outweigh most other costs. Even if you are using large objects a vector of (smart) pointers is likely to be faster than a linked list due to it being much simpler

Comment: FYI when I've implemented A-* search in the past, I've always used a [priority queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) backed by a vector. E.g. in my code I have `priority_queue<shared_ptr<Path>, std::vector<shared_ptr<Path>>, qcomp> q;`, where my `Path` is about the same as your `Node` -- a `Path` has a `shared_ptr` to its parent. And `struct qcomp
{
    bool operator()(const shared_ptr<Path>& p1, const shared_ptr<Path>& p2) const
    {
        return p1->f() > p2->f(); /* ordering refers to vector underlying priority_queue */
    }
};`

Comment: Be careful, `-ffast-math` should only be used if you are 100% aware of the potential consequences to your program. It can silently lead to incorrect results. I'd advise not to use it.