# Random slowdown when inserting elements at random into vectors

Tags: c++, performance, vector, slowdown

**EDIT:**
I've fixed the insertion. As Blastfurnace kindly mentioned the insertion invalidated the iterators. The loop is needed I believe to compare performance (see my comment on Blastfurnance's answer). My code is updated. I have completely similar code for the list just with vector replaced by list. However, with the code I find that the list performs better than the vector both for small and large datatypes and even for linear search (if I remove the insertion). According to http://java.dzone.com/articles/c-benchmark-%E2%80%93-stdvector-vs and other sites that should not be the case. Any clues to how that can be?

I am taking a course on programming of mathematical software (exam on monday) and for that I would like to present a graph that compares performance between random insertion of elements into a vector and a list. However, when I'm testing the code I get random slowdowns. For instance I might have 2 iterations where inserting 10 elements at random into a vector of size 500 takes 0.01 seconds and then 3 similar iterations that each take roughly 12 seconds. This is my code:

```
    void AddRandomPlaceVector(vector<FillSize> &myContainer, int place)  {
    int i = 0;

    vector<FillSize>::iterator iter = myContainer.begin();

    while (iter != myContainer.end())
    {
        if (i == place)
        {
            FillSize myFill;
            iter = myContainer.insert(iter, myFill);
        }
        else
            ++iter;

        ++i;
    }

    //cout << i << endl;
}

double testVector(int containerSize, int iterRand)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << containerSize << endl << "Random inserts: " << iterRand << endl;

    vector<FillSize> myContainer(containerSize);
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer tid;

    for (int i = 0; i != iterRand; i++)
    {
        double randNumber = (int)(myContainer.size()*((double)rand()/RAND_MAX));
        AddRandomPlaceVector(myContainer, randNumber);
    }

    double wallTime = tid.elapsed().wall/1e9;

    cout << "New size: " << myContainer.size();

    return wallTime;
}

int main()
{
    int testSize = 500;
    int measurementIters = 20;
    int numRand = 1000;
    int repetionIters = 100;


    ofstream tidOutput1_sum("VectorTid_8bit_sum.txt");
    ofstream tidOutput2_sum("ListTid_8bit_sum.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i != measurementIters; i++)
    {
        double time = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j != repetionIters; j++) {
            time += testVector((i+1)*testSize, numRand);
        }

        std::ostringstream strs;
        strs << double(time/repetionIters);
        tidOutput1_sum << ((i+1)*testSize) << "," << strs.str() << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != measurementIters; i++)
    {
        double time = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j != repetionIters; j++) {
            time += testList((i+1)*testSize, numRand);
        }

        std::ostringstream strs;
        strs << double(time/repetionIters);
        tidOutput2_sum << ((i+1)*testSize) << "," << strs.str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct FillSize
{
    double fill1;
};
```

The struct is just for me to easily add more values so I can test for elements with different size. I know that this code is probably not perfect concerning performance-testing, but they would rather have me make a simple example than simply reference to something I found.

I've tested this code on two computers now, both having the same issues. How can that be? And can you help me with a fix so I can graph it and present it Monday? Perhaps adding some seconds of wait time between each iteration will help?

Kind regards,
Bjarke

Comment: `AddRandomPlaceVector` should be `myContainer.insert(myContainer.begin()+place, myFill);` That for loop is slow and unneeded. Not 12 seconds slow though. Nothing here should take 12 seconds if your vector size is really 500.

Comment: Thanks Dave, please see my edit and comment on Blastfurnace's answer. Maybe you can give me a hint on that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddRandomPlaceVector` function has a serious flaw. Using `insert()` will [**invalidate iterators**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) so the `for` loop is invalid code.

If you know the desired insertion point there's no reason to iterate over the `vector` at all.

```
void AddRandomPlaceVector(vector<FillSize> &myContainer, int place)
{
    FillSize myFill;
    myContainer.insert(myContainer.begin() + place, myFill);
}
```

Comment: Ah, of course.

I thought of that, but then I would use the random access feature of vectors in my comparison between vectors and lists. As my comparison should illustrate a linear search (check for condition) then that would skew the performance. However, I will look into not invalidating my iterator!

Comment: So I've updated my original post, but found another issue. Maybe you can help me with that as well? :)

Comment: @user1452257: Are you testing an optimized/release build? Does the `list` code iterate over the __entire__ list on insert as well? I have to say that `std::vector` is a poor container choice if random insertions are the dominant operation.

Comment: No, I am testing a "debugging" build in CodeBlocks without any effort on optimization. That might be it. The code is exactly the same for the list. I could have the code not iterate over the entire container, but I guess if it is the same operation on the two containers then I won't matter. My thought is that "there just happens to be one element that fits the criteria", but the code should resemble a conditional search algorithm.

According to also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238008/relative-performance-of-stdvector-vs-stdlist-vs-stdslist I thought vector would be faster.

Comment: @user1452257: Oh yeah, profiling an unoptimized build isn't a good idea. The standard library containers and algorithms heavily rely on templates and __really__ benefit from compiler optimizations.

Comment: Is there some easy way to make it "optimized"? ;)

Comment: @user1452257: It depends on the compiler. I think CodeBlocks uses `gcc` (or is it `g++`) so the compiler command-line option `-O2` should enable optimizations. Not sure how to specify that in CodeBlocks. You should be able to google up an answer for that. Note that `-O2` is just one commonly used option, there are many more.

Comment: Thanks, -O2 worked brilliantly! Can you show me how to change my code to use templates so I can use "any" container and struct for testing? I've tried to contact you through chat, but I don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: @user1452257: Although the basics aren't complicated, _templates_ are a large subject. I'd like to help but I think you'd be better off following a good C++ book. Have you seen [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?