# What is the fastest way to implement a list and queue in c?

Tags: c, algorithm

Which one stack and queue realization will be faster and more optimal and why? Based on array (dynamic or static) or list?

For example, I have these ways:

Dynamic array based:

```c
typedef struct Stack {
    char* values;
    int avl_el;
    int now_el;
    int top;
}Stack;

void push(Stack* stack, char data) {
    if (stack->now_el >= stack->avl_el) {
        stack->avl_el += INCR;
        stack->values = (char*)malloc(stack->avl_el * sizeof(char));
    }
    if (stack->top == -1) {
        stack->top++;
        stack->values[stack->top] = data;
        stack->now_el++;
    }else {
        stack->top++;
        stack->values[stack->top] = data;
        stack->now_el++;
    }
}

char pop(Stack* stack) {
    char tmp = stack->values[stack->top];
    stack->values[stack->top] = 0;
    stack->top--;
    stack->now_el--;
    return tmp;
}
```

List based:

```c
typedef struct Node {
    char data;  // in this case we save char symb
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    struct Node* topElem;
}Stack;

void push(Stack* stack, char data) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(1 * sizeof(Node));
    if(!tmp) {
        printf("Can't push!\n");
        return;
    }
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = stack->topElem;
    stack->topElem = tmp;  // making new top element
}

char pop(Stack* stack) {
    Node* tmp = stack->topElem;
    char del_data = stack->topElem->data;
    stack->topElem = stack->topElem->next;
    free(tmp);
    return del_data;
}
```

Will be any different with stack based on dynamic and stack based on static arrays?

Comment: Run benchmarks and see for yourself?

Comment: Considering that your first implementation is wrong (you throw away all elements when increasing the size) and leaks memory I think you should first worry about fixing that before worrying about performance

Comment: @JohnColeman, I need an answer акщь the part of the algorithm, not just the running time. How to justify this theoretically?

Comment: @UnholySheep, Yes, I understand it and that's hastily realization just for example and to express more clearly my question. Also, with my test, it works normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you fix your bugs, let's discuss the principles. The biggest performance bug is incrementing size with a constant INC. With this bug, the complexity for inserting n elements is O(n<sup>2</sup>). For better  complexity, reallocate in multiples of 2 or 1.5, after the fix the complexity of inserting n elements becomes O(n), or amortized O(1) for a single insertion.

The two approaches have been tested extensively with C++: what is faster `std:: vector` (similar to your stack) or `std::list` (a doubly linked list). Here is a list of resources:

- [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://youtu.be/YQs6IC-vgmo), the creator of c++, compared lists and vectors.
- [stack overflow: Relative performance of std::vector vs. std::list vs. std::slist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238008/4955498)

Lists are easier to implement, and have a better predictability (no resizing), but vectors are faster in the stack scenario on average, and more memory efficient.

**Vectors (the stack in the question):**

Size: No need to store pointers to the next element. So it's more efficient.

Speed: consecutive elements are near each other, resulting in better memory predictability, and higher cache efficiency.

**lists:**

Size: no need to find one big block of memory (works better in a fragmented memory).

Speed: predictable - no need to copy big chunks of memory once in a while.